# glDrawArrays with multiple triangles in a single array with a persistent first and count

Tags: c, opengl, optimization

I have a bunch of polygon data that I want to draw. I pulled out that drawing code so that it currently looks like this

```
for (int Index = 0; Index < Count; Index++) {
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, Index * 4, 4);
}
```

I have a giant one dimensional array filled with multiple triangles, a new triangle every 4 vertices. Are there any OpenGL functions that I can replace this entire loop with so that I don't have the overhead of each glDrawArrays call? glMultiDrawArrays is sort of what I want, except I don't need a different first (well, I need a different first, but multiplied by a constant) and count each time.

I thought something like glVertexAttribDivisor would work, but nothing was drawing after I added it, I'm not completely sure if it works without instancing either.

EDIT: I am using a triangle fan, and I am buffering the vertices every frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`glDrawElements()` + [`GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART` & `glPrimitiveRestartIndex()`](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Primitive_Restart).

Comment: Does the element array need to contain indices for every single triangle in the big array, or only enough to define one triangle (it's actually a quad, but using two triangles and it'll share two indices)?

Comment: @badcc: Every one.  On the plus side it'll be easy to populate and won't need to change frame-to-frame, so you can just toss them into a big VBO and forget about it.

Comment: I do need to change it every frame, though (I think?). I am drawing 2d shadows, so not only are the positions always changing, but the number of them is always changing.

Comment: @badcc: The positions can go in a separate vertex VBO.  `glDrawElements()` takes a `count` argument so as long as your index VBO is long enough for the maximum # of shadows you plan on rendering you can just adjust `count` downward to read only part of it.